# Unable to see Git changes like Intellij in Eclipse

Tags: java, git, eclipse

When I use Intellij, I'm able to use git in the local terminal. Also all the uncommited changes are visible while coding, making the whole process of working with git easy.

I'm currently working on a maven project in Eclipse. I right-click on the project, click on local terminal and then git bash. The process is almost the same.

The only problem I'm facing here is that Eclipse doesn't show me the uncommitted changes. I have tried to use stuff like Egit but it seems too complex.

What changes should I make to see my uncommitted changes while coding in Eclipse? Please help, really struggling with it.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Getting_Started

Comment: I'm surprised because I use the standard Eclipse installation without any additions and the status of all files is displayed in the package explorer. It shows the branch, if I have pushed or not and what files are changed. Not sure how you have missed it?

Comment: Make sure you have "Git integration for Eclipse" installed and not just "Java implementation of Git".

Comment: In Eclipse all uncommitted changes are listed in the _Git Staging_ view and when choosing in the preferences _General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff_ as reference source _A Git revision_ instead of _Version of Git_, the changed lines will also marked in the overview ruler.